# Error 3192 when try insert record in sql server

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a strange problem: I do an insert into command using as usual example:

```vb
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim sql As String

Set dbs = CurrentDb
sql = "INSERT INTO dbo_tblScheMod (Stato, Collezione, Modello, Articolo) VALUES ('x','x','x','x');"

dbs.Execute sql
```

I get error:

> Could not find output table dbo_tblScheMod.(Error 3192)

The table dbo_tblScheMod exists and visible in the Access environment in the Tables section.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Are you *sure* you're using SQL Server? Error 3192 in SQL Server is *"Restore was successful but deferred transactions remain. These transactions cannot be resolved because there are data that is unavailable. Either use RESTORE to make that data available or drop the filegroups if you never need this data again. Dropping the filegroup results in a defunct filegroup."*

Comment: That's an Access error message.